Is there a way to override matplotlibs rectangle zoom so that it zooms in one dimension only so it behaves like MATLAB without holding X or Y?
This post asks a similar question: link
The answer is to draw a box while holding X or Y to zoom in that dimension only. In MATLAB you can perform this type of zoom while drawing a thin rectangular box. While drawing the box I would like zoom only in the X dimension if its a thin horizontal box or the Y dimension if it's a thin vertical box, since this is more familiar to MATLAB users. Is there a way to write your own zoom functionality for the rectangular zoom?

Indeed, you can override Matplotlib's rectangle zoom behavior to zoom in one dimension (either X or Y) but you need to modify the event handler for zoom actions. By default, Matplotlib's rectangle zoom zooms in both dimensions, but you can customize this behavior.
# Custom zoom function to only zoom in the X direction
def zoom_factory(ax, zoom='x'):
   def zoom_event(event):
       # Get current limits
       xlim = ax.get_xlim()
       ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    
       # Get coordinates of the zoom rectangle
       x0, y0 = event.xdata, event.ydata
       x1, y1 = ax.transData.inverted().transform((event.x, event.y))
       
       if zoom == 'x':  # Only zoom in X direction
           ax.set_xlim([min(x0, x1), max(x0, x1)])
           ax.set_ylim(ylim)  # Keep Y limits unchanged
       elif zoom == 'y':  # Only zoom in Y direction
           ax.set_xlim(xlim)  # Keep X limits unchanged
           ax.set_ylim([min(y0, y1), max(y0, y1)])
    
       ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

return zoom_event

